# UpdateSourceTrigger's Default vs PropertyChanged?

Tags: wpf, binding

```
<TextBlock Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

"Name" is the property of an object which is bound with the TextBlock at runtime. I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged so the code is working fine. My question is: if I replace PropertyChanged to Default will it still work? What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx), the `UpdateSourceTrigger`'s default value is `PropertyChanged` for most properties and `LostFocus` for the `TextBox.Text` property.

In your case, you're probably binding to a property for which the default is already set to `PropertyChanged`, so you won't see any difference.

Answer (score 1):

`PropertyChanged` is telling `Binding` that whenever you receive `PropertyChanged` notification for that property, update it's value on destination.

For some controls, like `TextBox`, using `Default`, it only updates binding destination when for example, it loses focus. When you set `UpdateTrigger='PropertyChanged'` on it, it will update binding destination while you are typing.

Answer (score 0):

For TextBox Control
When we use UpdateSourceTrigger=Default means when source object loses focus, value in target will get updated.
When we use UpdateSourcetrigger=PropertyChanged means when source object text changes(even when we type a single character) immediately than change will be reflected in target.
Above case is for TextBox control as default for most control is PropertyChanged only